# Avoiding Shadowing in Typescript for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following component that should display an error message based upon the codes it's being asked to check for as well as the conditions of the controls passed to it:

```ts
import {
  Component,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl
} from '@angular/forms';

export interface ErrorCodeMessage {
  code: string;
  message: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-field-errors',
  templateUrl: './field-errors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field.errors.component.scss']
})

export class FieldErrorsComponent {
  @Input() controls: AbstractControl[];
  @Input() formSubmitted: boolean;
  @Input() errorsToTest: ErrorCodeMessage[];

  public controlsAreNotPristine(): boolean {
    let arePristine = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.controls.length; i++) {
      arePristine = arePristine && this.controls[i].pristine;
    }
    return !arePristine;
  }

  public controlsHaveError(code: string): boolean {
    let haveError;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.controls.length; i++) {
      haveError = haveError || this.controls[i].hasError(code);
    }
    return haveError;
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="controlsAreNotPristine() || formSubmitted">
  <div *ngFor="let error of errorsToTest" [hidden]="!controlsHaveError(error.code)" [translate]="error.message"></div>
</ng-container>
```

This is obviously not working because the variables `arePristine` and `haveError` are being shadowed since I'm using the `let` operator. TSLint does not want me to use `var`, however! How would I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: Try using `this.controls.some(c => c.hasError(code))` and `this.controls.some(c => c.pristine))`

Comment: In general, you can also do that kind of thing with reduce: `this.controls.reduce((prev, curr) => prev && curr.pristine, true);`.

Comment: Actually I believe `Array.prototype.some` is precisely what I need, testing it now...

Comment: Yup, that works, though it should be `this.controls.some(c => !c.pristine))` ;)
Thanks a lot @yurzui!

Comment: Just to note, shadowing has nothing to do with `let`. Shadowing is a fundamental part of JavaScript's scope resolution mechanism and applies to all names.